# service dependency injection templated using inheritance

Tags: c#, design-patterns, software-design

What are the pros and cons of using a template pattern (inheritance) for injecting dependencies for a class.

Let’s say I am creating a bunch of business service classes, for example, ISecurityService implemented as SecurityService.

And, if I know all of the business services (including ISecurityService) will/should depend on IBusinessContext for service context information, can I use a template pattern (using inheritance) to achieve/enforce that?

Approach #1:

```
public interface IBusinessContext
{
   public int Property { get; }
}

public interface IService
{
   public IBusinessContext Context { get; }
}

public abstract class ServiceBase : IService
{
   public IBusinessContext Context { get; }

   public ServiceBase(IBusinessContext context) { _context = context; }
}

public interface IBusinessServiceN : IService
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public class BusinessServiceN : ServiceBase, IBusinessServiceN
{
   public SecurityService(IBusinessCnotext context)
          : base(context) { }

   public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

Approach #2:

```
public interface IBusinessContext
{
   public int Property { get; }
}

public interface IBusinessServiceN
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public class BusinessServiceN : IBusinessServiceN
{
   private IBusinessContext _context;

   public SecurityService(IBusinessCnotext context) { _context = context; }

   public void DoSomething() { }
}
```

Which approach is preferred and why?

Comment: Presumably your constructor in #2 should be `BusinessServiceN` not `SecurityService`?

Comment: Your `private IBusinessContext _context` should ideally be `readonly` in #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2 because why does it make sense for a service to expose `IBusinessContext` as a public property? It doesn't. That's one of its dependencies and it doesn't need to be exposed through an interface or even on the concrete class.

The contract for consuming an `IService` isn't / should not include the contract for creating a concrete class to fulfill `IService`. If I can implement `IService` without an instance of `IBusinessContext` that's a good thing, especially when it comes to writing unit tests and mocking an `IService`. Or what if my `IService` implementation needs an `ICompleteContext` instead that includes an `IBusinessContext`, again that should not be constrained artificially with some interface as you do in #1.

Comment: IBusinessContext might contain information about the environment/context (user context and other business related context information) in which the BusinessServices operate which shall be injected using DI.

Comment: @Param Yes, great, and if a concrete class needs that it will necessarily take a dependency on it in its constructor, but if, say, it needs more than that it might depend on a 'larger' interface that includes `IBusinessContext`, or if later you split that context into, say, two interfaces it might only need part of it. Or suppose you later add an `IService` that doesn't need an `IBusinessContext`, maybe a crypto service or something similar? etc. But none of this should have anything to do with the contract for what that class exposes _up_ through it's exposed interface.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirements. Unless you have a reusable code in your abstract class, Approach #1 does not add any benefit.

The Template Method pattern really shines when you have a common workflow and you are certain that this workflow does not change;and while Child Implementations may change certain steps, they may not change the workflow structure.

So suppose in your DoSomething method you have a "strict" workflow, with some steps common to inheriting classes:

```
public virtual void DoSomething() {
        DoSomethingFirst(); // -> common to all classes
        DoSomethingAfter(); //-> each class has unique implementation
}
```

Your base class can take the form:

```
 public abstract class ServiceBase : IService
{
    public IBusinessContext Context { get; }

    public ServiceBase(IBusinessContext context) { Context = context; }

    public void DoSomethingFirst() {
        // common implementation here
    }

    public abstract void DoSomethingAfter();

    public virtual void DoSomething() {
        DoSomethingFirst(); 
        DoSomethingAfter();
    }
}
```

And your concrete class:

```
 public class BusinessServiceN : ServiceBase, IBusinessServiceN
{
    public BusinessServiceN(IBusinessContext context)
           : base(context) { }

    public override void DoSomethingAfter()
    {
        //Your custom implementation here
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have an imposed structure in your `DoSomething()` method and a shared/reusable `DoSomethingFirst()` method.

Comment: Yes, I agree that BaseClass is used to template methods. But, I am thinking if it is ok to template or constraint context information as properties which are injected via a constructor.